# Div appears mis-aligned and inside another div

Tags: html, css

I am making a mock website for a school projevt and I have a problem with my div elements being mis-aligned and appearing in another div.

Here is what it looks like currently
[http://i.imgur.com/A6zKQoA.jpg]

Here is what I want it to look like (made with photoshop) [http://i.imgur.com/Gv2yOgJ.jpg]

Html

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <font color="BB9B5D"><h3><strong>LATEST NEWS</strong></h3></font>
 <hr color= "bb9b5d" />

  <div id= "LN1">
   <img src="Images/Fillerino.jpg" name="lni1" id="lni1" align= "left">
   <h4>Update 1.1.0</h4>
   <p>The first update of this year is here! Download it now and play with your friends, and be the first to take down the new bosses. </p>
  </div>

  <div id= "Ln2">
   <img src="Images/Fillerino.jpg" name="lni2" id="lni2" align= "left">
   <h4>Patch Notes 1.1.0</h4>
    <p> Read up on the Official Patch Notes to find out what you're up against.</p>
  </div>

</div>

 <div id= "NR">
  <font color="BB9B5D"><h3><b>RELEASES</b></h3></font>
  <hr color= "bb9b5d" />
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

NR is another element to the right but it is working as intended

CSS

```
#wrapper {
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background-color: #202020;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-top: 1px;
 padding-bottom: 600px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 font-family: Roboto-Light;
 min-width: 55%;
 max-width: 55%;
 float: left;
}
#NR {
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 background-color: #202020;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-top: 1px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 300px;
 font-family: Roboto-Light;
 min-width: 32%;
 float:right;
}
#LN1 {
 font-family: Roboto-Light;
}
#lni1 {
 width: 20%;
 height: 20%;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
#LN1 {
}
#lni2 {
 width: 20%;
 height: 20%;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
```

I've tried adding margins and padding to both ln1 and ln2, Id also rather not change use position absolute as I want to add more divs under them in similar formatting.

Any help would be highly appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Side note, the `<font>` element doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I see id `Ln2` in your html, but NOT in your css. I recommend keeping your IDs in mixed case, and perhaps more meaningful ID names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're aligning the images to the left, you'll need to define clear float.

```
#LN1, #Ln2 {
      clear: both;
    }
```

```css
#wrapper {
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background-color: #202020;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-top: 1px;
 padding-bottom: 600px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 font-family: Roboto-Light;
 min-width: 55%;
 max-width: 55%;
 float: left;
}
#NR {
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 background-color: #202020;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-top: 1px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 300px;
 font-family: Roboto-Light;
 min-width: 32%;
 float:right;
}
#LN1 {
 font-family: Roboto-Light;
}
#lni1 {
 width: 20%;
 height: 20%;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
#LN1, #Ln2 {
  clear: both;
}
#lni2 {
 width: 20%;
 height: 20%;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <font color="BB9B5D"><h3><strong>LATEST NEWS</strong></h3></font>
 <hr color= "bb9b5d" />

  <div id= "LN1">
   <img src="Images/Fillerino.jpg" name="lni1" id="lni1" align= "left" />
   <h4>Update 1.1.0</h4>
   <p>The first update of this year is here! Download it now and play with your friends, and be the first to take down the new bosses. </p>
  </div>

  <div id= "Ln2">
   <img src="Images/Fillerino.jpg" name="lni2" id="lni2" align= "left" />
   <h4>Patch Notes 1.1.0</h4>
    <p> Read up on the Official Patch Notes to find out what you're up against.</p>
  </div>

</div>

 <div id= "NR">
  <font color="BB9B5D"><h3><b>RELEASES</b></h3></font>
  <hr color= "bb9b5d" />
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't realise you also had to clear for align, thought it only applied to float.

Comment: @LuthexColbark It is actually, you're not wrong but it's the browser that applies float when you use the align attribute in img tag, which is deprecated so I'd recommend replacing it with a css rule. check out display: inline-block if you want to avoid using float. Thanks for the check :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can add like this css html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <font color="BB9B5D"><h3><strong>LATEST NEWS</strong></h3></font>
 <hr color= "bb9b5d" />

  <div id= "LN1" class="test">
   <img src="Images/Fillerino.jpg" name="lni1" id="lni1" align= "left">
   <h4>Update 1.1.0</h4>
   <p>The first update of this year is here! Download it now and play with your friends, and be the first to take down the new bosses. </p>
  </div>

  <div id= "Ln2" class="test">
   <img src="Images/Fillerino.jpg" name="lni2" id="lni2" align= "left">
   <h4>Patch Notes 1.1.0</h4>
    <p> Read up on the Official Patch Notes to find out what you're up against.</p>
  </div>

</div>

 <div id= "NR">
  <font color="BB9B5D"><h3><b>RELEASES</b></h3></font>
  <hr color= "bb9b5d" />
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.test{display: inline-block; width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should solve your problem. Replace the image

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
    <style>
    p{
        color:white;
    }
    #wrapper {
     margin-top: 20px;
     margin-left: 20px;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     background-color: #202020;
     padding-left: 30px;
     padding-top: 1px;
     padding-bottom: 600px;
     padding-right: 30px;
     font-family: Roboto-Light;
     min-width: 55%;
     max-width: 55%;
     float: left;
    }
    #NR {
     margin-right: 20px;
     margin-top: 20px;
     background-color: #202020;
     padding-left: 30px;
     padding-top: 1px;
     padding-right: 30px;
     padding-bottom: 300px;
     font-family: Roboto-Light;
     min-width: 32%;
     float:right;
    }
    #LN1 {
     font-family: Roboto-Light;
    }
    #lni1 {
     width: 20%;
     height: 20%;
     margin-right: 10px;
    }
    #LN1 {
        float:left;
    }
    #lni2 {
     width: 20%;
     height: 20%;
     margin-right: 10px;
    }
    h4{
        color:white;
    }
    #Ln2{
        float:left;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
     <font color="BB9B5D"><h3><strong>LATEST NEWS</strong></h3></font>
     <hr color= "bb9b5d" />

      <div id= "LN1">
       <img src="yellowbg.jpg" name="lni1" id="lni1" align="left">
       <h4 >Update 1.1.0</h4>
       <p>The first update of this year is here! Download it now and play with your friends, and be the first to take down the new bosses. </p>
      </div>

      <div id= "Ln2">
       <img src="yellowbg.jpg" name="lni2" id="lni2" align="left">
       <h4>Patch Notes 1.1.0</h4>
        <p> Read up on the Official Patch Notes to find out what you're up against.</p>
      </div>

    </div>

     <div id= "NR">
      <font color="BB9B5D"><h3><b>RELEASES</b></h3></font>
      <hr color= "bb9b5d" />
     </div>

    </body>
    </html>
</body>
```